# Translate a general urllib2.Request to curl command

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, urllib

How can I programmatically convert `urllib2.Request` object into the equivalent `curl` command?

My Python script constructs several `urllib2.Request` objects, with different headers and postdata. For debugging purposes, I'd like to replay each request with `curl`. This seems tricky, as we must consider Bash escaping and urllib2's default headers. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to debug? Have you just tried turning on logging?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be to run wireshark to capture the desired requests and then replay them with a packet replay tool like TCPreplay. If you do want to modify parts in curl for debugging wireshark will show you all the headers urllib2 is setting so you can set them the same in curl.